# Access MySQL Kubernetes Deployment in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I deployed a MySQL pod with the example from the kubernetes website: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/

I can access the pod from the pod network but not from outside the cluster, how can I achieve this? I would want to access the service via MySQL Workbench for easier editing of the Database.

I already tried to setup a NodePort service like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3006
    nodePort: 30003
  selector:
    app: mysql
  type: NodePort
```

with the goal to access the service at :30003 but that does not work.

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that you requested `<NodeIP>:30003` to connect the the service? Also what k8s cluster is this? Minikube has different approach for this as an example.

Comment: I actually had a typo in my configuration, emberrasing. In the snippet above, the targetPort is 3006 instead of 3306, thank you for the comment, it pushed me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3006
    nodePort: 30003
  selector:
    app: mysql
  type: NodePort
```

the targetPort is 3006 instead of 3306, it was a typo.