# Access MySQL Single-Instance Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

I was following the [Run a Single-Instance Stateful Application](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/) tutorial of Kubernetes (I changed the MySQL docker image's tag to 8), and it seems the server is running correctly:
[image]

But when I try to connect the server as the tutorial suggesting:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --image=mysql:8 --restart=Never mysql-client -- mysql -h mysql -ppassword
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.1.0.99' (using password: YES)
> pod "mysql-client" deleted

---

I already looked at those questions:

- [Can't access mysql root or user after kubernetes deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460113/cant-access-mysql-root-or-user-after-kubernetes-deployment)
- [Access MySQL Kubernetes Deployment in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205150/access-mysql-kubernetes-deployment-in-mysql-workbench)

But changing the `mountPath` or `port` didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default behavior of `root` account can only be connected to from inside the container. Here's an updated version of the example that allows you to connect from remote:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:8.0.26
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST
          value: "%"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        emptyDir: {}
        # Following the original example, comment the emptyDir and uncomment the following if you have StorageClass installed.
        # persistentVolumeClaim:
        #  claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

No change to the client connect except for the image tag:

`kubectl run -it --rm --image=mysql:8.0.26 --restart=Never mysql-client -- mysql -h mysql -ppassword`

Test with `show databases;`:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error:
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.1.0.111' (using password: YES)
pod "mysql-client" deleted
pod default/mysql-client terminated (Error)`. Maybe something to do with the PersistentVolumes? I'm not sure I correctly understood this requirement:
`You need to either have a dynamic PersistentVolume provisioner with a default StorageClass, or statically provision PersistentVolumes yourself to satisfy the PersistentVolumeClaims used here.`

Comment: The updated answer allows you to switch storage.

Comment: The updated answer is working thank you! But can you please explain what the value "%" for the host means? And maybe refer me to how to install a StorageClass?

Comment: It means all hosts are allowed to connect, the value can be in CIDR format, too. You can start [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) and setup the StorageClass that suit your infra.